# How to return the access-modifier level of an Object's property in PHP?

Tags: php, class, object, access-modifiers

say I have this class :

```
class Foo {
  var $pu = 0;
  private $pr = 1;
}
```

I need to find a way to check the access modifier level of one property, for instance :

```
class Foo {
  var $pu = 0;
  private $pr = 1;

  function return_all_public () {
    $publics = [];
    for (get_object_vars($this) as $key => $value) {
      // if $this->{$key} is public then array_push($publics, $key);
    }
    return $publics;
  }
}
```

This is just an example, the function is not what I try to achieve, just I want to know how to check the level of the access modifier of one property (public, protected or private ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ReflectionObject`:

```
foreach ((new ReflectionObject($this))->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC) as $property) {
    $publics[] = $property->getName();
}
```

Or even:

```
$publics = array_map(function (ReflectionProperty $property) {
    return $property->getName();
}, (new ReflectionObject($this))->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC));
```

References:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionobject.php
http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php
http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionproperty.php

Comment: thanks, is this the only way ? I mean isn't it possible to produce the same result only using the native function of php ? (not using extra Object Instanciation)

Comment: There's no such "native function" that I'm aware of, no. And this is also perfectly "native" code, it just happens to use an OO interface. That should't be any reason against using it.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT To clarify - dont use this, it is clearly a bug, that appears to have been fixed in php version 7.** http://codepad.viper-7.com/lyULdW (change version to <=5.6 to see it working)

The answer by @deceze is the most robust, but as you indicated a preference for function calls without instantiating a new object:

```
class Foo 
{
    var $pu = 0;
    private $pr = 1;

    function return_all_public () {
        return call_user_func('get_object_vars', $this);
    }
}
```

Whether this scope issue is a feature or a bug is unclear!

Comment: O_o What is this, I don't even... Please don't do that in actual code, it's somewhere between misleading and confusing.

Comment: @deceze yeah, i know - i upvoted your answer,and hopefully made it clear that this "feature" might get fixed!

Comment: @deceze On further investigation, it has already been fixed! I made an edit